# Suspending Vs. Powering Off My VM

Tags: suspend, power-management

If there is a difference, which option uses up more battery life?
When is it better to power off the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In both cases (suspended / powered-off) the VM doesn't consume battery.**

---

The major difference between those two modes:

- Suspend writes memory to disk and the Guest OS enters hibernate/sleep state
- Powers off the virtual machine. The virtual machine does not attempt to shut down the guest operating system gracefully.

[More info from VMWARE online library](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/bsa/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=bsa&file=BSA_Managing_VMs.13.3.html)